# Merge/combine two objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two different arrays from two different sources that I need to merge to form a new array. Here are the two arrays:

```
[
    {
        "Litsname": "Fruit Basket",
        "Listid": "1",
    }
]
```

And,

```
[
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Apples",
        "categoryID": "2",
        "categoryName": "Fruits"
    },
    {
       "id": "5",
        "name": "Orange",
        "categoryID": "2",
        "categoryName": "Fruits"
    }
]
```

I want to merge/combine them to form the following array:

```
[
    {
        "Litsname": "Fruit Basket",
        "Listid": "1",
        "item": [
            {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "Apples",
                "categoryID": "2",
                "categoryName": "Fruits"
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "name": "Orange",
                "categoryID": "2",
                "categoryName": "Fruits"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Tried to use jQuery extend but it doesn't look like it's appropriate for this. Any help on how I can achieve this with either jQuery/plain JavaScript?

Comment: There is no such thing as a “JSON object”. You might be converting this JSON into objects, and then you're dealing with those objects (in this case, a couple of arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the first one is called `a` and the second one is called `b`, then you just need to say `a[0].item = b`